# Get a parent and the children using a child ID or the parent ID

Tags: mysql

I have a hierarchical table with 2 levels of depth – that is, parents and children.

Having a parent ID, I want to extract the parent and its children.

Having a child ID, I want to extract the parent and the other children related of that parent.

I've come up with the following query that seems to work OK:

```
SELECT *
FROM album a
JOIN (
    SELECT IFNULL(a.parent_album_id, a.album_id) parentalbumid
    FROM album a
    WHERE a.album_id = 64
) t1 ON t1.parentalbumid = IFNULL(a.parent_album_id, a.album_id)
```

But is this the most optimal way of achieving my goal?

Comment: Please provide the table structure and EXPLAIN output. The optimal query might depend o your amount of data, indexes, ...

Comment: I would use one of well known structures for trees. Bill Karwin reviews them in http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557 . Each of them has pros and cons, it's up to you to decide what works better for you. Whatever you choose execution plan will be optimal.